# The letters A, E, I, P, Q, and R are arranged in a circle. Find the probability that at least 2 vowels are next to one another.

Tags: probability, permutations

I've had trouble for his one for a while now. All help would be greatly appreciated.

My attempt:
Alright, since one letter is fixed, that leaves us with 5 letters to arrange. I'm going to fix the consonant in this case, since it is particularly easier for me :P. The remaining spots (5 left) can be arranged 3!*2! (remaining vowels and consonants respectively). I'm lost here though, so any help on what to do/correct me would help. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

There are $6$ chairs around a table. The chairs are labelled $1$ to $6$, in counterclockwise order.

The letter $P$  sits down somewhere, it doesn't matter where, say on the chair labelled $1$. Then the other letters sit down at random. We will find the probability that the vowels are all **separated**.

If the vowels are to be all separated, they must occupy chairs $2$, $4$, and $6$, and the remaining two consonants must occupy $3$ and $5$.

There are $\dbinom{5}{2}$ ways of selecting two chairs for the consonants, from the remaining five. There is exactly $1$ selection that consists of chairs $3$ and $5$.

I expect you can now complete things.

Answer (score 2):

A few broad hints:

1. Since the letters are arranged in a circle, you can choose to 'start' the circle anywhere you wish, so you can just set the 'A' at twelve O'clock for reference purposes; that leaves one less symmetry that needs consideration.
2. Ignore the *specific* consonants and vowels for a minute and imagine that you have V, V, V, C, C, and C.  How many distinct ways can you arrange those letters (with a 'V' at 12 o'clock, remember!) so that none of the Vs are next to each other?
3. Now that you know all the possible configurations of V's and C's, can you go back for each of those configurations and figure out how many possible assignments of vowels into the Vs (remember, your A is still fixed!) and how many possible assignments of consonants into the Cs there are?  (Keep in mind that for each possible C-and-V set, the arrangement of individual vowels into the Vs and individual consonants into the Cs are independent; this means that you can just multiply the number of vowel arrangements by the number of consonant arrangements to get the total number of arrangements for a given configuration.)
4. Once you've done this for each configuration of Vs and Cs, you can just add up the total number of arrangements per configuration to get the total number of 'good' arrangements.  Can you figure out how to get the total number of arrangements?  (Keep in mind that we're keeping the 'A' fixed at the top, still!)  Once you have the two numbers, you should be able to just divide them out to get a probability...

Comment: Hey, if it doesn't bother, would you mind giving me the answer, so I can see whether I did it correctly?

Comment: @missiledragon To be honest, I'd rather see your attempt (and answer) edited into the question!

Comment: I placed my attempt, however, I'm still pretty stuck :(

Comment: @missiledragon You skipped into step 3 without doing step 2 at all; I really recommend doing step 2 first.  After that, try doing step 4 (in particular, for the second half of step 4 you can _ignore_ the vowel-consonant distinctions...)

Comment: I think I arrived at the answer: 1-(3!*2!/5!)